# Add HTTP headers to SOAP request with data from external API using Interceptor

Tags: java, soap, cxf, interceptor

I am attempting to implement a logic where I add some HTTP headers to my SOAP request before sending the request onwards to the target webservice. More specifically I am attempting to implement signing HTTP messages as described in this [IETF draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-cavage-http-signatures-12). My implementation needs to be applied to a multitude of webservices and therefore agnostic with respect to this.

I am relatively new to SOAP, and Apache CXF which I am using. But my thought was to create an Interceptor implementation which could be easily added to the relevant SOAP-services in my apps. My attempt looks like this.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.AbstractSoapInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
import org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;

public class MyInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        // Fetch headers
        Map<String, List<String>> requestHeaders = (Map<String, List<String>>) message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS);

        // Fetch request-body as String, this seems a bit hacky...
        OutputStream outputStream = message.getContent(OutputStream.class);
        CachedOutputStream cachedOutputStream = (CachedOutputStream) outputStream;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            cachedOutputStream.writeCacheTo(builder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        String requestBody = builder.toString();

        // External API requires the HTTP headers and body
        Map<String, List<String>> headersToAddToRequest = externalApiService.fetchSignedHeaders(requestHeaders, requestBody);

        // Add headers to message
        message.put(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS, headersToAddToRequest);

    }

}
```

Now this seems to "work", but it feels a bit "hacky". Is there an "easier" way to achieve this, or any big mistakes in the logic here?

Sorry If such an open-ended question is disallowed. Feel free to close this if it doesn't comply with SE guidelines.